# Retrieve ARVector3 from touch on cameraView

Tags: ios, iphone, augmented-reality, kudan

I've been playing around with the enhanced samples and read the full SDK documentation but I'm can't figure out this problem. I'm trying to convert a touch on the self.cameraView to a ARVector3 so I can move the 3D model to that position. At the moment I'm trying to convert the CGPoint from the tapGesture to the world ARNode but no luck so far.

```
float x = [gesture locationInView:self.cameraView].x;
float y = [gesture locationInView:self.cameraView].y;
CGPoint gesturePoint = CGPointMake(x, y);
ARVector3 *newPosition = [arbiTrack.world nodeFromViewPort:gesturePoint];   

ARNode *touchNode = [ARNode nodeWithName:@"touchNode"];
ARImageNode *targetImageNode = [[ARImageNode alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"drop.png"]];
[touchNode addChild:targetImageNode];
[targetImageNode scaleByUniform:1];

touchNode.position = newPosition;
[arbiTrack.world addChild:touchNode];
```

This results in the following situation:
[image: Rendered world as schema]

And seen on my iPhone:

[image: iPhone screenshot]

Why is a touch in the upper left corner of the self.cameraView a point that is closest by? I actually want to click on the screen and get a X, Y, Z (ARVector3) coordinate back.